# Custom table mapping for OData endpoint

Tags: sql, odata

I've successfully completed a few examples used to create Web API Odata services.  Such as:

- Create model class "Employee"
- Create controller "EmployeesController"
- Use GET /Employees to get list of records

These examples would create a SQL table called "Employees".  How would I map this model\controller to an existing SQL table called "corpemployee"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the sql statement first and map the result to the Employee object, for example:

```
public class EmployeesController:ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        string sql="select * from corpemployee";
        // Create a database connection
        // Execute the sql statement
        IList<Employee> employees=new List<Employee>();
        Employee employee=new Employee();
        foreach(var result in resultset)
        {
             Employee employee=new Employee(); 
             emmployee.ID=result["ID"];
             // Other properties go here
             employees.Add(employee);
        }
        return Ok(employees);
    }
}
```

Definitely there are other options, such as using O/R mapping framework:

1. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/NHibernateQueryableSample/.
2. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataDollarFormatSample/, which uses Entity Framework.